# File processing with integers

Tags: java, database, file, stream

I am trying to process both strings and integers from a collection of records. Each record has various columns for each parameter. I process each piece of information from a datastream.

The stream contains the various values like:

```
Key       Time        Seconds
Af3w      50:34       480
```

I process the strings like:

```
stream.readFully(keyPad);
key = new String(keyPad);
```

and now `key = "Af3w"`. (`keyPad` is a variable to help pad the number of bytes I will need to read).

However, when I try to process seconds as an integer, I get a weird value.

```
seconds = stream.readInt()
```

Seconds ends up being equal to `876097545` instead of `480`, however when I process it as a string and parse it as an int I get `480`. This is only a simple solution however because integers can **range** from `3` characters to `8`, so I need to process it as an `int`.

So my question is why is it when I read the integer from the stream, I get the value `876097545` instead of `480`.

Comment: Might be that someone could actually answer it, if there was any code to work with... Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise this question was nothing except a waste of time for both you and everyone who reads this.

Comment: My apologies, I don't want to make it seem like I'm posting my entire code and suggesting someone fix it for me. I just want to know why the value "480" is processed as "876097545" when being read as an int from a datastream in java, but also as "480"' when processed as a string.

Comment: While thats a nice gesture, it doesn't exactly help here. There could be tons of reasons. For example we don't know what `stream` is, or how it's initialized. Might be that you accidentally read over a few values, etc.. You should post the code and point out as clear as possible what you want to know. Otherwise there isn't much we can do except blind guessing, which won't lead to anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "480" is saved in the stream as a characters, not an integer.
When you go to read an integer, you pull in 0x343830nn. 8 bytes for an integer in java. If nn = 00, The integer equivalent is 876097536 so I'm guessing the next byte in the stream is 0x09 which will yield 876097545.